# how to check if a mail server exists or not?

Tags: php

my PHP page currently doesnot have a mail server, instead of throwing an error, is it possible to catch this error and print it out to the user?

this is what I have so far, it just gives an error.

```
<?php 
$foo = mail('test@test.com', 'subject', 'message');
if ( $foo == false )
{
echo "no mail server";
}
?>
```

thanks!

Comment: Does this really make sense - presumably, you are going to install your script once, aren't you? And on the server, there will either be or not be a mail server installed?

Comment: @Pekka: Perhaps he's creating a user-friendly setup script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could open a port to the mail server in question using fsockopen('servername/ipaddres', 25); If it returns content, it means the port is open and that you could ASSUME that there is a mail server.

```
$errno = 0;
$errstr = '';
$fp = fsockopen("localhost", 25, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "No mail server responded on this server on port 25, validate your configuration";
}
```

This is by all means very experimental, you need to involve yourself in more work but it should get you started :)

Comment: Be careful with this idea: Port 25 is the (obsolete) port for receiving email, not sending it. It is common for a secondary machine to be able to send mail but not receive it. (Incoming mail would go to the main mail machine.) So testing for the presence of a port 25 handler is *not* a good way to determine if a machine can send email.

Comment: Like i said, this should be considered as a starting point. The script should requrest many more information such as ipaddress or hostname of the mail server to use and port to connect to. BTW, if you want something serious, you should consider using a library to send emails such as SwiftMailer, not the internal Mail function.

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` could fail for other reasons than just a non-existant mail server. I think the best you can do is fail gracefully and show the user the message you got, and even that has limitations.

In PHP 5.1 and above, you could catch the error in the following way:

```
error_reporting(0); // Don't display errors
$success = mail(....); 

if (!$success) 
 {
  echo "Mailing failed: Error message: ".error_get_last();
 }
```

if you need to support older versions than that, I think you'll have no option than showing the raw error message from mail() - you could theoretically suppress it, but that will  not show the user what exactly went wrong.